# Android: Fatal exception issue: attempting to call method on click of a button

Tags: android, exception, button, methods, logcat

I am a bit of a novice at writing applications and I'm working on a school project. I've just about finished the program, just debugging now. I'm having a major issue that can't seem to get around involving calling a method on the click of a button. The program is intended to download a file after the user types in a search term.

Originally, my logcat was telling me the method could not be found in the HelloTabWidget class. I originally had the findSong method in the SearchActivity class, so I moved pretty much all of the code from SearchActivity into HelloTabWidget, since that seemed like an easy way to see everything anyway. Now, I've tried the tip on here of changing the path in the xml fro onClick but that didn't fix it either. Rather, I got the past error from before: "could not find method com.android.iPirate.HelloTabWidget.findSong in activity HelloTabWidget..." I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the added exception in the method. But I'm virtually clueless as to what can be done to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's HelloTabWidget:

```
package com.android.iPirate;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

>import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SearchActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost


        // Do the same for the other tabs

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("Instructions",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_settings))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2); }

    public String searchTerm;
    public String quotes = "";
    public String title;
    public EditText edittext;
    public String youTubeURL;
    public Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();


        public void findSong(View view) throws Exception {
            edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext); 
            searchTerm = edittext.getText().toString();
            String address;
            address = getURL(searchTerm);
            UrlDownload.fileUrl(address, title + ".mp3", "/");
        }

        public void findPlaylist(View view) throws Exception{
            findSong(view);
            String[] pageNames = getLinks(youTubeURL);
            for(String name : pageNames)
                if (!names.contains(name))
                    UrlDownload.fileUrl(getURL(name), title + ".mp3", "/");
        }

        public static String[] getLinks(String link) throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    url.openStream()));
            Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
            String[] songs = new String[15];
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                songs[i] = nextTitle(input);
            return songs;
        }

        public static String nextTitle(Scanner input){
            while (input.hasNextLine()){
                String inputLine = input.nextLine();
                if (inputLine.contains("<span dir=\"ltr\" class=\"title\" title=\"")){
                    return inputLine.substring
                    (inputLine.indexOf("<span dir=\"ltr\" class=\"title\" title=\"") + 37, inputLine.indexOf(">")-1);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getURL(String searchString) throws Exception {
            String searchQuery = searchString.replace(' ','+');
            String siteURL = new String("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+searchQuery+ "&aq=f\"");
            URL url;
            url = new URL(siteURL);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
            String videoLink = "";
            String fLink = null;
            while(input.hasNextLine()){
                String line = input.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("<!-- start search results -->")){
                    for(int i = 0; i <= 44; i++){
                        line = input.nextLine();
                    }
                    youTubeURL = "www.youtube.com/"+line.substring(line.indexOf("<a href=")+8, line.indexOf("class")-2);
                    videoLink = "http://www.video2mp3.net/index.php?url=" + youTubeURL;
                    title = line.substring(line.indexOf("title="+6),line.indexOf(quotes,line.indexOf("title")+7)-1);
                    names.add(title);
                    break;
                }
            }
            URL vurl = null;
            vurl = new URL(videoLink);
            BufferedReader in2;
            in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(vurl.openStream()));
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(in2);
            while(input2.hasNextLine()){
                String line = input.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("Conversion successfully completed!")){
                    line = input.nextLine();
                    line = input.nextLine();
                    fLink = line.substring(line.indexOf("http"),line.indexOf("/'"));
                    break;
                }
            }
            URL furl;
            furl = new URL(fLink);
            BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(furl.openStream()));
            Scanner input3 = new Scanner(in3);
            while(input3.hasNextLine()){
                String line = input.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("Wait 20 seconds or click here")){
                    line = input.nextLine();
                    String line2 = input.nextLine();
                    String line3 = input.nextLine();
                    String line4 = input.nextLine();
                    if(line2.contains(".mp3"))
                        return line.substring(line.indexOf("tt"+3)) + line2.substring(0,line2.indexOf(".mp3")+4);
                    else if(line3.contains(".mp3"))
                        return line.substring(line.indexOf("tt"+3)) + line2 + line3.substring(0,line3.indexOf(".mp3")+4);
                    else if(line4.contains(".mp3")){
                        return line.substring(line.indexOf("tt"+3)) + line2 + line3 + line4.substring(0,line4.indexOf(".mp3")+4);
                    }
                }
            }   
            return "";
        }

        public void savemp3(String s) throws Exception{
            URLConnection conn = new URL(s).openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File(title + ".mp3"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            outstream.close();
        }
    }
```

Now the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find Song"
        android:onClick="findSong" />
        <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find Playlist"
        android:onClick="findPlaylist" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>




    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.android.iPirate"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
  <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
          <activity android:name=".SongsActivity"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

and Logcat:

```
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.android.iPirate.HelloTabWidget.findSong(HelloTabWidget.java:71)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     ... 11 more
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1020)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1152)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:653)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.android.iPirate.HelloTabWidget.getURL(HelloTabWidget.java:111)
12-06 14:35:33.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4157):     ... 15 more
```

Thanks for any help.

New logcat:

```
>12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at com.android.iPirate.HelloTabWidget.findSong(HelloTabWidget.java:71)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     ... 11 more
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870): Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     at com.android.iPirate.HelloTabWidget.getURL(HelloTabWidget.java:129)
12-06 16:34:30.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4870):     ... 15 more
```

And thanks to the people helping me with the quotes. Can't figure them out! :D

Comment: Are you able to access `www.youtube.com` using the browser on that device?

Comment: Yes. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's because you're opening a socket, but didn't declare the `INTERNET` permission.  Try adding this to your manifest outside the <application> tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. That removed the socket exception. The app now seems to be going through some work first rather than just quitting immediately when I push the button. But I still have the first couple exception issues. I posted the new logcat in my original post.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Look at your logcat: UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.youtube.com:80

Comment: Yes, I've tried running it on an emulator and an actual device and I get the same log.

Comment: I fixed the UnknownHostException by adding ,line.indexOf("http") in the fLink line. Still getting the IllegalStateException. I use the findSong method to create a string and a bad string could be the cause of the other errors, so I'm looking to fix the IllegalStateException. Anyone?

Comment: Well, you'll need to update the logcat again in your question.

Comment: Well, let's read what it says: `java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: `. Can you print out the exact URL you're giving it? Are you prepending `http://`?

Comment: I'm not really worried about the 2nd and 3rd exceptions, because the first error involves the creation of a string that is used as a URL, which would explain the malformed URL. Something is wrong with findSong. I tested URLDownload separately and it worked seamlessly so that's not the problem in findSong. So it has something to do with getURL. I've been looking through it and don't see anything in particular. If anyone sees something in there, please let me know. I plan on testing it tonight/tomorrow morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never try to rename main class when you create from eclipse.

create a new project and add the files. 
and try to run again.

Answer (score 0):

Which line in your HelloTabWidget.java file is line 111? You have a `SocketException` being raised in your 'getURL()' method.

Comment: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the last logcat output it seems like the URL you are passing it is malformed. try to log the URL using `Log.d()` and check out what the URL really looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I used a TabHost once and I got a very similar error like you. The fault in my case was in my  Manifest. I made a spell error, the activity i added to the manifest was written like this: .list instead of .List that's what made me get the error. The only thing what was wrong was just one letter not being upper case :). To find an error, firstly get your code in a try catch block for more control, and this helps you to find out what exceptions exactly is thrown  and why. An after that you will probably find your problem.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to not set `onCLickLIsteners` in XML. Do it in code.

Comment: -1: Why not? It's clearly not the issue here, and it's a convenient way to add a listener, which also requires less code and clutter. It's still as debuggable as an in-code listener (assuming you are capable of reading logcats :) ). Okay, disclaimer - I never use onClick myself, but just because I'm an old-fashioned bastard doesn't mean the practice of onClick should be discouraged.

Comment: Well I didn't read the whole question, since I'm not going to go through 5 pages of code. But the title suggests he's having problems with the onclick.